# Cannot form expression of type with two question marks in Java

Tags: java, generics

I can neither compile nor refactor the following code to work:

```
public class DoubleQuestionMark {

   public static class Paired1<P,R> {
   }

   public static class Paired2<P,R> {
   }

   public static class Paired3<P,R> {
   }

   // regard it as third party method, not allowed to change signature
   public static <S> void perform(Paired1<Paired2<S,?>, Paired3<S,?>> argument) {
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Paired2<Integer, ?> p2 = new Paired2<>();
      Paired3<Double, ?> p3 = new Paired3<>();

      Paired1<Paired2<Integer, ?>, Paired3<Double, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();

      perform(p1); // cannot be applied to given class

   }
}
```

How to prepare an object, acceptable by `perform` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass two different types for the same type parameter `S`.

`Paired1<Paired2<S,?>, Paired3<S,?>>` Both `S` must be of the same type:

So this will work:

```
Paired1<Paired2<Integer, ?>, Paired3<Integer, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();
perform(p1);
```

But this will not:

```
Paired1<Paired2<Integer, ?>, Paired3<Double, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();
perform(p1);
```

If you need to pass two different numeric types, both Integer and Double extend Number. So you can use:

```
Paired1<Paired2<Number, ?>, Paired3<Number, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();
```

Comment: See my new qstn pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659369/attempt-2-cannot-form-expression-of-type-with-two-question-marks-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Note that the type of `argument` is:

```
Paired1<Paired2<S,?>, Paired3<S,?>>
```

So the `Paired2` and `Paired3` are required to have the same type `S` for their first type argument.

You are trying to use two different types here, `Integer` and `Double`:

```
Paired1<Paired2<Integer, ?>, Paired3<Double, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();
```

The classes `Integer` and `Double` have a common superclass `Number`. It works when you change the line above to the following:

```
Paired1<Paired2<Number, ?>, Paired3<Number, ?>> p1 = new Paired1<>();

perform(p1); // ok
```

Comment: See my new question pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659369/attempt-2-cannot-form-expression-of-type-with-two-question-marks-in-java